# FloatBuffer draws textured quad, but ShortBuffer doesn't

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to draw a textured quad. Since it is a quad I want to use `glDrawElements` and a VEO, but that requires a `ShortBuffer` instead of a `FloatBuffer`. I tried changing my code, but now nothing draws.
Old code:
Uploading and drawing:

```
 public void flush() {
    if (numVertices > 0) {
        vertices.flip();

        if (vao != null) {
            vao.bind();
        } else {
            vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
            specifyVertexAttributes();
        }
        program.use();

        /* Upload the new vertex data */
        vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        vbo.uploadSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices);

        /* Draw batch */
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);

        /* Clear vertex data for next batch */
        vertices.clear();
        numVertices = 0;
    }
}
```

Adding texture to buffer:

```
if (vertices.remaining() < 7 * 6) {
        /* We need more space in the buffer, so flush it */
        flush();
    }

    float r = c.getRed();
    float g = c.getGreen();
    float b = c.getBlue();
    float a = c.getAlpha();

    vertices.put(x1).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t1);
    vertices.put(x1).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t2);
    vertices.put(x2).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t2);

    vertices.put(x1).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t1);
    vertices.put(x2).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t2);
    vertices.put(x2).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t1);

    numVertices += 6;
```

Updated code:
Uploading and Drawing:

```
public void flush() {
    if (numVertices > 0) {
        vertices.flip();

        if (vao != null) {
            vao.bind();
        } else {
            vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
            specifyVertexAttributes();
        }
        program.use();

        /* Upload the new vertex data */
        vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        vbo.uploadSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices);

        /* Draw batch */
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);

        /* Clear vertex data for next batch */
        vertices.clear();
        numVertices = 0;
    }
}
```

Adding texture to buffer:

```
if (vertices.remaining() < 7 * 6) {
        /* We need more space in the buffer, so flush it */
        flush();
    }

    short r = (short) c.getRed();
    short g = (short) c.getGreen();
    short b = (short) c.getBlue();
    short a = (short) c.getAlpha();

    short sx1 = (short) Math.round(x1), sx2 = (short) Math.round(x2), sy1 = (short) Math.round(y1), sy2 = (short) Math.round(y2), ss1 = (short) Math.round(s1), ss2 = (short) Math.round(s2), st1 = (short) Math.round(t1), st2 = (short) Math.round(t2);
    vertices.put(sx1).put(sy1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(ss1).put(st1);
    vertices.put(sx1).put(sy2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(ss1).put(st2);
    vertices.put(sx2).put(sy2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(ss2).put(st2);

    vertices.put(sx1).put(sy1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(ss1).put(st1);
    vertices.put(sx2).put(sy2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(ss2).put(st2);
    vertices.put(sx2).put(sy1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(ss2).put(st1);

    numVertices += 6;
```

There were no other changes to the code, except replacing `FloatBuffer` with `ShortBuffer` in my `uploadSubData` method. The VBO class is just a wrapper for the OpenGL methods, so `uploadSubData` is `glUploadSubData`, etc...
What am I missing? Why doesn't `glDrawArrays` draw the `ShortBuffer`?
If I left out anything, please tell me, I didn't have much time to write this.

Comment: I've had a similar problem before when trying use IntBuffers instead of FloatBuffers. Nothing I did seemed to work, so I just continued using FloatBuffers in the end. The performance impact shouldn't be too big, so I think you'll be fine just using FloatBuffers too.

Comment: " glDrawElements and a VEO, but that requires a ShortBuffer instead of a FloatBuffer". This is not true. The `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` stays a float buffer (or whatever you were using before. But you need an additional `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` which stores index information (int, short, etc.).

Comment: How is it not true, whenever I pass GL_FLOAT to glDrawElements, it throws an error. It only allows shorts, bytes, or ints. I am using glDrawArrays instead of glDrawElements because it accepts shorts, and is a good first step, If I can get glDrawArrays, then I will change it to glDrawElements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing indices and vertex coordinates. The coordinates are tuples of type `GL_FLOAT` in an `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. But the indices are a list of integral indices (e.g. type `GL_SHORT`) in a  `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` which refer to the vertex coordinates.

A quad can be be drawn by 2 triangles. You can define 6 vertex coordinates and attributes and use [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml).

In the following `vertices` is of type `FloatBuffer`:

```java
vertices.put(x1).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t1);
vertices.put(x1).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t2);
vertices.put(x2).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t2);

vertices.put(x1).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t1);
vertices.put(x2).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t2);
vertices.put(x2).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t1);

numVertices += 6;
```

```java
vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
vbo.uploadSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);
```

Or you can define 4 vertex coordinates respectively attributes and 6 indices and use [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml).

In the following `vertices` still is of type `FloatBuffer`, but `indices` is of type `ShortBuffer`:

```java
vertices.put(x1).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t1);
vertices.put(x1).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t2);
vertices.put(x2).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t2);
vertices.put(x2).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t1);

numVertices += 4;
```

```java
indices.put(0).put(1).put(2);
indices.put(0).put(2).put(3);

numIndices += 4;
```

```java
vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
vbo.uploadSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices);
ibo.bind(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
ibo.uploadSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, indices);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, GL_SHORT, numIndices, null);
```

So the key is that you'll need 2 `uploadSubData` methods. The former hast to deal with `FloatBuffer` and the later has to deal with `ShortBuffer`.
Note, in common the vertex attributes are floating point values. Colors are often floating point values in the range [0, 1]. Texture coordinates are in range [0, 1]. Of course it is possible to encode this to an integral data type, but at least for the vertex coordinates this would cause a loss of accuracy.

Comment: Thanks! I was so confused on the usage of the method, your clarification is so helpful.